# how to reset variables and cancel any active stream and reset everything in app

Tags: flutter, dart

i am building app that contains the following

1- global `variables` (depend on user inputs)  .

2- `StreamSubscription` for `firstore` listen `functions`  .

3- other active tasks like `await-async` function , timers , audio global instance .

4- and many active tasks i cannot remember them all .

users can switch their account to another by `sign-out` using firabse `auth` then login to another account .

now what i am doing before user switch his account is manually cancel and dispose and reset the whole variables within a function like following

```
void reset everything (){
// here i am trying my best to remeber everything and reset it like 

    variableName = '' ;
    streamName.cancel();
    .. and many ,any ,any others 

   then .. `sign out` 
    }
```

i have huge variables and streams i cannot remeber them all to reset them . is there away to stop everything is active and reset the whole variables .

I want this as if the application was configured from the first launch

How can i make sure that everything is stopped and reset from old account before user switch to another account .

Comment: What if you restart the application completely if a new user is signed in? Everything that you don't directly persist (like shared prefs) will start from scratch.

Comment: this is what i looking for .. yes i would like to keep shared prefs data .. i don't want to clear it .. i only mean about other tasks .. ok can you please tell me how to do restart app from within the app ?

Comment: There is a package for it, I use it for a while now without any problems: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix

Comment: if you have a way to call  app restart .. please write answer to accept it .. because when i kill  my app then open it again everything back to it's default value and this result what i looking for

Comment: Try this package, I hope it will solve your issue! Good luck.

Comment: thanks for sharing this package Peter . i will chick it